# How dense is SRAM compared to random logic?

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, integrated-circuit, sram, chip-design

Modern CPUs always have some on-chip cache, typically more than one level. This takes a lot of die area; static RAM is generally reckoned at six transistors per bit.

That having been said, the preponderance of area taken by static RAM, is not quite what you would expect just from raw transistor count; such a regular structure takes less area per transistor than the random logic constituting the rest of the CPU.

Roughly how much denser is static RAM than random logic? Would it be approximately accurate to say that it typically takes half as much area per transistor, or a third as much?

Comment: SRAM is a lot denser than logic on most modern nodes.

Comment: I suspect that SRAM (and DRAM) are the last holdouts for hand optimization.  There's no human way to hand-optimize a million transistors worth of logic, but hand-optimizing a million transistors worth of SRAM is a matter of hand-optimizing one little six-transistor cell, and then telling your computer to replicate it 170 thousand times.  Ditto DRAM, only more so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a very rough idea from the published transistor densities, with the caveat that real products are often dramatically different then isolated cells. For example, TSMC 7nm has a 0.027 square micron SRAM cell. That's 222 million transistors per mm square:

https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/7_nm_lithography_process

Conversely, they claim only about 90 million transistors per mm square for logic, so more than double the density.